# How to make list of dynamic list of generic class where T: struct?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, struct

I have a problem with making list of generic types where type argument is dynamic and struct. I think it'd be the best to just put example here.

```
public class Container
{
    public List<B<dynamic>> someList = new List<B<dynamic>>();

    public void AddToList(Type type)
    {
        var genericType = typeof(B<>);
        var generic = genericType.MakeGenericType(type);

        someList.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(generic) as B<dynamic>);
    }
}

public class B<T> where T : struct
{

}
```

How can I get something like this to work without getting

> error CS0453: The type 'dynamic' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'B'

Scenario is making system of items for my game. Game itself is in entity component system architecture so that everything in game is entity with some components(structs). I am making Item class which is ScriptableObject(sort of template which can be saved to xml file). I want every instance of Item to have this item specific components with item specific values in them. But the thing is I don't want each instance of this item to be the same but I would like this item to have some random values in specified range. I made it so that Item has list of ComponentSetup<>(B<> in my example) which takes Components(structs) and using reflection creates min/max values for each property Component has. In Item I need to access some functions of ComponentSetup so i need to make list of ComponentSetup<> but can't specify it as ComponentSetup< dynamic> becasue it takes only T where T : struct

Comment: Why do you need the type parameter for `B` to be `dynamic`?

Comment: Why do you think a `dynamic` is a struct?

Comment: `dynamic` is a fancy word for "`object` plus do magic at call-sites" - it will never be `struct`, and **cannot** be `struct`. What is the actual scenario you're trying to work with here? If we understand the scenario, we can probably offer much better guidance

Comment: I need a list of this generic class B but with multiple different argument structs

Comment: @MarcGravell I know what dynamic is and I know that I cannot use this in this case but is there anything simlar to dynamic but for structs?

Comment: @ArekŻyłkowski not directly, no; but: again, if you can advise on **what you are trying to do**, I suspect we can help; so, again: what scenario are you trying to cover here?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is thread necro, but for the benefit of the OP and anyone stumbling upon this same situation, I was trying to achieve the exact same thing as the OP.
Here's how I've solved and implemented this issue in my game:

Unity's file are `MonoScript`s, and as such, are not really valid types. When we drag scripts or game objects to the inspector, Unity uses reflection to extract useful types and methods from within the scripts.

`MonoScript` provides `GetClass()` which returns the `class` or `struct` defined within, but there was a bug reported about it returning error if the struct was defined within a namespace - in my case, it returned null:

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/monoscript-dot-getclass-returns-null-when-the-script-contains-a-struct-inside-a-namespace-or-an-interface-inside-a-namespace

So, for anyone trying to implement something similar, where you'd want to pass generic objects as custom scripts (component structs) or populate a list of components, cast the entry to `MonoScript` and call `GetClass()` avoiding defining the type within a namespace. Here's some pseduo-implementation for clarification:

```cs
// Assuming retrieving list of components from a List<UnityEngine.Object>
foreach (entry in componentList) {
    Type ComponentType = (entry as MonoScript).GetClass();
    var component = Activator.CreateInstance(ComponentType);
    entity.AddComponent(component);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you are going to achieve, but if you supply your generic class with this method, you could add its instances to dynamic list

```
public class B<T> where T : struct
{
    public dynamic GetDynamic()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```